# Flipping status of records without regression over time

Tags: sql

Not sure how to look for this, so I'm sorry if this was asked before.

Supposedly I am supplied with a collection of records. These records carry a certain status, which is either `true` or `false`. Over time, our client would want a specific subset of the documents to be switched from one state or another.

So currently the records are stored in a SQL database (PostgreSQL to be exact). So in order to keep a history of the flipping of status (and also to ensure we can rerun everything from scratch in case something screwed up), we have all the update statements stored in a version-controlled repository. However, because this is SQL, and after a while the SQL becomes super complicated (to ensure no regression, i.e. not setting the status to `true` when it was previously requested to be `false`).

For example, we received ticket #1 and #2 in the past to flip records to `true` and `false` respectively

```
-- DO THIS FOR TICKET #1
UPDATE  record
SET     status = TRUE
WHERE   id IN (SELECT  id
               FROM    records
               WHERE   this_criteria = 'that');


-- DO THIS FOR TICKET #2
UPDATE  record
SET     status = FALSE
WHERE   id IN (SELECT id
               FROM   records
               WHERE  another_criteria = 'whatever')
```

This is what we do when we have a ticket #3 where it involves a subset of records in #1 and #2

```
-- DO THIS FOR TICKET #3
UPDATE  records
SET     statue = TRUE
WHERE   id IN (SELECT  id
               FROM    records
               WHERE   true_criteria = 'something')
        AND id NOT IN (-- regression ticket #1
                       SELECT  id
                       FROM    records
                       WHERE   this_criteria = 'that'
                       UNION
                       -- regression ticket #2
                       SELECT  id
                       FROM    records
                       WHERE   another_criteria = 'whatever');
```

So what we are doing now is to run the update statement for #1, then followed by #2, lastly #3. As expected, #3 will take forever to run. I can optimize the query, but it is still not going to help in the long run, as future tickets will be causing more and more complicated conditions being written to avoid overwriting the status set in the previous ticket(s).

Now that we are looking for an alternative to the approach for another project, and we are expecting to have the status flip to happen far more frequently in the future. What could be a better way to manage this, and if possible, provide a way for us to actually log the changes (doesn't have to be SQL)?

Instead of doing it in batches, we are shifting towards update them incrementally over time (imagine we send the records into a pipe one after another periodically, and each request of client is a box to flip record's status if applicable, finally those records will be upserted to some data store). So we are replacing SQL into some rule-based mini DSL to ensure the condition is met before flipping the status. However, that doesn't look like an improvement to the SQL method, because sooner or later the condition will grow due to regression check, and the rules are practically just SQL in another format.

An example of the new one for ticket #3 would be some thing like this

```
SET status TO TRUE
CONDITION (is_equal, true_criteria, 'something') # new ticket #3 request
          # REGRESSION in ticket #1
          AND (not_equal, this_criteria, 'that')
          # REGRESSION in ticket #2
          AND (not_equal, another_criteria, 'whatever')
```

As you can see while I don't have to do it to all records at once like SQL, the statement above is really just a variation to the original SQL counterpart.

EDIT:

1. This is not about SQL optimization, I can also implement this without using relational database, and then I can remove the identifier column. The status variable is not determined by the value of the identifier.
2. Assuming I am gonna throw the collection into a search appliance, i.e. ElasticSearch, so it would be nice if I can pre-compute the status, so I don't have to attach a huge query DSL on top of user issued query, to ensure only `status=true` records are returned.
3. I am looking for an alternative solutions, that do not have to be implemented in relational database (hence i removed the `postgresql` tag).
4. The client does not always care if their new request will caused the some of the previously set status to flip, they just want to ensure the previously flipped statuses are not implicitly rewritten when the new condition is applied.
5. In the SQL implementation, we made a mistake of not logging the changelog for the status field, and the one we are drafting will be having that, so yes, we have to have a way to log the status flip.

Comment: is the id field unique?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't really matter here, I am not looking for SQL optimization actually, but more a strategy on how other people does this

Comment: at Jeffrey04 Yes, it *does* matter, because your subqueries refer to exactly the same record as the target record for the update statement. See @BennjoeMordeno 's answer. Also: your status is actually redundant, since it can be (re)computed from the other columns.

Comment: it is redundant, but it would be costly if you keep having to calculate the value on the fly right? let's just say if the status is true, i want it to be searchable with elasticsearch. I certainly don't want to attach a huge query DSL just to ensure the status is true before serving the search result.

Comment: also id field being unique or not is not relevant here, because i might implement it with no identifier if I don't use relational database, and the value of the identifier does not determine the status at all

Comment: @joop updated the question to attempt to better describe what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Test this on your sample data, but I think you can simplify your `in` clause and get rid of `not in` clause like below

```
UPDATE  records
SET     statue = TRUE
WHERE   id IN (SELECT  id
           FROM    records
           WHERE   true_criteria = 'something'
           and this_criteria <> 'that'
           and another_criteria <> 'whatever'
           )
```

Comment: no, i am not looking for an optimization of the SQL, because the condition will grow over time. also separating the `IN` and `NOT IN` actually helps making it readable (IN = for new request, NOT IN = for regression handling)

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID` field is unique you can simplify your query to:

```
   UPDATE records
   SET STATUS = TRUE
   WHERE 
   true_criteria = 'something'
   and
   this_criteria <> 'that'
   and
   another_criteria <> 'whatever'
```

Although I think you may be looking at another table for the subqueries, then this won't do.

Comment: no, i am not looking for an optimization of the SQL, because the condition will grow over time. also separating the `IN` and `NOT IN` actually helps making it readable (IN = for new request, NOT IN = for regression handling)

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear what you are asking. If you want a simple way to include exclude the conditions from the other tickets you can just chain them, putting them into `this_column (not) IN(a,b,c)` lists. (assuming that id is the primary key for your records table)

---

```
-- DO THIS FOR TICKET #3
UPDATE  records
SET     statue = True
    -- No need to flip it if it is already True
WHERE status <> True
    -- New condition for ticket #3
AND true_criteria IN ( 'something')
    -- regression ticket #1
AND this_criteria NOT IN( 'that' )
    -- regression ticket #2
AND another_criteria NOT IN ('whatever')
    ;
```

Comment: I was asking what would be an alternative approach to implement this (not necessarily relational database, hence I don't need suggestions on how to optimize the query)

Comment: implement some mechanism that would make writing the conditions easier (without overwriting previous state) with the possibility to log every status flip